# Special syntax of java try catch block

Tags: java, try-catch

```
Charset charset = Charset.forName("US-ASCII");
try (BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(file, charset)) {
    String line = null;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
} catch (IOException x) {
    System.err.format("IOException: %s%n", x);
}
```

I saw such a piece of code on [The Java Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/file.html), in which a bracket statement is after key word 'try'. Is this valid? why cannot eclipse  recognize it and report syntax error?

Comment: (I wonder why they have that redundant assignment.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the Java 7's [try with resource](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) feature.

You need to set Eclipse's Compiler Compliance level to 1.7 for it to recognize the syntax.

You can either set it globally under `Window > Preferences > Java > Compiler` or simply right-click on the project and do as shown below:

[image]

Comment: The OP says: "*why cannot eclipse recognize it and report syntax error?*" - his Eclipse recognizes this syntax, it already works with 1.7 JDK...

Comment: Further Question：I installed JRE1.7 into Eclipse(by Windows-Preference-Java-Installed JRE) and was able to import related packages. But I cannot find 1.7 in Executation Env, and also cannot set Complier compliance level as 1.7. WHY?

Comment: @user796857 Because what you need is the JDK, not the JRE.

Answer (score 1):

This is a [*try-with-resource*](http://www.theserverside.com/tutorial/Use-try-with-resources-Language-Enhancements-for-the-Java-7-OCPJP-Exam) syntax introduced in Java 7. It is [supported by Eclise](http://www.eclipse.org/jdt/ui/r3_8/Java7news/whats-new-java-7.html#try-with-resources), that's why it is not reporting any error:

[image: Eclipse]

BTW your code also uses [`Files`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html) introduced in Java 7.

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse clearly indicates why this is not valid syntax:

> Set project compiler compliance settings to 1.7
>
> Set project JRE build path entry to 'JavaSE-1.7'

That means, you have Java 6 installed, but the tutorials

> (...) primarily describe features in Java SE 7.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/index.html

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not valid.  Try this:

```
Charset charset = Charset.forName("US-ASCII");
try {
    BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(file, charset);
    String line = null;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
} catch (IOException x) {
    System.err.format("IOException: %s%n", x);
}
```

Comment: This question is not tagged "java 7", so this answer is correct given the (reasonable) assumption that we're in java 6 land

Comment: Agree, but it looks like the OP simply wasn't aware of Java 7 existence and features. BTW Java 6 end of life is scheduled for this November: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/eol-135779.html