# Why is my Java BufferedReader reading nulls at file start and end?

Tags: java, bufferedreader

I am having trouble seeing what is wrong with the code below. It is outputting nulls when there aren't any.

output: `null This is one. This is two. This is three. This is four five six. seven? null`

The contents of the file:

```
This is one.
This is two.
This is three.
This is four
five
six.
seven?
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!

```
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename))) {

    String cLine="";
    while ((cLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
        content+= cLine;

    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

System.out.println(content);
```

Comment: Show how content is initialised, probably set to null

Comment: Also, prefer using a [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) to repeatedly concatenating strings.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suspect `content` is null to start with (rather than empty) which explains the first `null`. It doesn't explain the last one, admittedly... My guess is that you've actually fixed a bug since you saw the output with `null` at the end. Either that or your file *actually* has `null` at the end. (I've tested it with `content` initialized to "" and it's fine.)

Are you aware that you're removing all line breaks though, and not replacing them with any kind of delimiter? So a file with lines of "x", "y" and "z" will become just "xyz".

Additionally, consider using a `StringBuilder` rather than string concatenation - it'll be more efficient as it won't need to copy the string all the time.

Comment: just wondering for my own knowledge, would BufferedReader return null if it detected a carriage return? So, possibly the 2nd null is an empty line under 'seven?'

Comment: @ChristopherDay: Nope - it would return an empty string for an empty line. It *only* returns `null` at the end of the stream.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer that. I know it's off topic from the main question.

Comment: Thanks Jon, you were correct. The second null was caused by a system.out in a minimized method.

Answer (score 0):

Just a comment...

I didn't know this syntax of try. Initially I thought it was a typo but I found that it actually works ( I compiled it and ran the code).

I thought it was always :
try {
....
....
....
} catch() {}

on further reading, found that this was a new feature of Java 7 , "try with resource" (from [Special syntax of java try catch block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9582053/special-syntax-of-java-try-catch-block))

Answer (score -2):

If your starting out with Java I suggest something simpler... like using a Scanner on the file instead. Ponder the following:

```
Scanner fileRead = new Scanner(fileName);

while ( fileRead.hasNextLine() ) {
    System.out.println( fileRead.nextLine() );
}
```

My suggestion anyways.

Comment: If he is new at Java it's easier to start in simpler ways, it's merely a suggestion. If it's about him learning and not just getting an answer I would consider it useful.